# JavaScript complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am doing some basic algo problem with JavaScript on a page call codility. There is one problem I encountered but cannot figure out the root cause.
It is the complexity of the function below, the analysis show the code is O(n**2)

From my searching, the Object.keys is surely O(n), therefore it can only be the first two loop which is doing the adding and deleting keys to and out of an object. I wonder which is the cause of O(n**2) here. Do you guys have any ideas or any instruction that help me test it out ?

[image]

The image below here is another test that shows it only about O(n) or O(nlogn) when doing the adding keys to object in javascript. Can we conclude from this that the problem causing O(n**2) in the above function is due to the deleting???

[image]

Comment: An O(n) loop that calls an O(n) function like `delete` would be O(n^2).

Comment: What tool is that ?

Comment: If you want to determine the O() of the `delete` function empirically, you could run a simple test in your tool by just running `delete`.

You can also look to your algorithms class to see the common ways of deleting an element from an array, which often require shifting down the other elements.

Comment: Do you know where I can look up for the JavaScript complexity of basic things in JavaScript such as object, array functions, etc,